# how to re-ask a user for input if none was given the first time?

Tags: ruby

My current code is this:

```
print "Feed me input."
def get_input
    input_value=gets.chomp
    if !input_value
      print "you didn't type anything"
    else
      input_value.downcase!
      if input_value.include? "s"
         input_value.gsub!(/s/,"th")
      else 
         print "You entered a string but it had no 's' letters."
      end
    end
   return input_value
end
get_input()
if !get_input
  get_input
  else 
    puts "#{get_input}"
end
```

I'm not sure why it isn't working. When I run it I get prompted for input then when I press enter after entering none I get the "You entered a string but it had no 's' letters", not the "you didn't type anything" that I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every object except `false` and `nil` is treated as `false` if they are used as predicates. Even empty string is treated as `true`:

```
s = ""
puts true if s # => true
```

Use [`String#empty?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-empty-3F) to check if it is empty string.

Comment: So I replaced the !input_value and !get_input with String#empty?. Now the code tells me I didnt type anything no matter what I do.

Comment: @macsplean, Replace `if !input_value` with `if input_value.empty?`.

Comment: @macsplean, In the code, I modified `get_input` to return modified input when it is valid (containing `s`), or return `nil`. And does not used `"#{get_input}"` because it call `get_input` again.

Comment: do you mind explaining the while loop at the bottom? I am not familiar with the `while ! (line = get_input)` `end` `puts line` format.

Comment: @macsplean, It call `get_input`, then assign the result value of the function to `line`. The return value is either `String` object or `nil`; so now `!` is work as expected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38654/discussion-between-macsplean-and-falsetru)

Answer (score 2):

As you said *When I run it I get prompted for input then when I press enter after entering none* - It means what happened acctually is

```
 input_value="\n".chomp #( you gets methods take only `\n` as input)
 "\n".chomp # => ""
```

so your `input_value` variable holds and empty string object. ***Now in Ruby every object has `true` value, except `nil` and `false`.*** Said that `""` is also true,but you did `!input_value`,which means you are making it `false` explicitly. That's the reason in the below `if-else` block, *else* part has been executed and you didn't see the expected output **"you didn't type anything"**.

```
if !input_value
      print "you didn't type anything"
    else
      input_value.downcase!
      if input_value.include? "s"
      #.. rest code.
```

So I would suggest you in such a context replace the line `if !input_value` to `if input_value.empty?`, Which will make your code to behave as you are expecting. I didn't take your logic as a whole,but tries to show you how to code to meet your needs:

```
print "Feed me input."
def get_input
    input_value=gets.chomp
    if input_value.empty?
      puts "you didn't type anything"
      false
    else
      puts "found value" 
      input_value.downcase!
    end
end

until input = get_input
   # code
end
puts input
```

**output**

```
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~/Ruby$ ruby test.rb
Feed me input.
you didn't type anything

you didn't type anything

you didn't type anything
HH
found value
hh
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~/Ruby$
```

Comment: I tried replacing all instances of !get_input and !input_value with input_value = "/n" and get_input = "/n", respectively, but the outcome was the same as before.

Comment: I tried replacing the !input_value and !get_input with input_value.empty? and get_input.empty?. Now I am told I didn't type anything. I am then prompted to type something again, and then I type 's', expecting it to replace the 's' with 'th', but it doesn't work. The program just stops (without an error).

Comment: @macsplean see now if I can help you now fully or not.